# Android ActivityThread.reportSizeConfigurations causes app to freeze with black screen and then crash

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

I have a crash in my app. It happens for a lot of users and its multiple places in ActivityThread.java method reportSizeConfigurations. I dont know what this is used for, and why it freezes.

The freeze happens right after the splash screen (when the main activity is started) and is only happening on upgrading of the app. If you reinstall the application the problem goes away. Problem is, I cant tell all the users to reinstall the application...

Does anyone know what might cause this and why? It seems maybe to be connected with some DB handling, but thats just a guess.

Heres the stacktrace from Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reportSizeConfigurations: ActivityRecord not found for: Token{a28a055 null}
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1697)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.reportSizeConfigurations(ActivityManagerNative.java:8342)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.reportSizeConfigurations(ActivityThread.java:3049)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2992)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Heres the stacktrace from play store 'ANRs & crashes':

```
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 TimedWaiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74864f70 self=0x7f8b896a00
  | sysTid=28578 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8f832a98
  | state=S schedstat=( 237746089 66838748 1069 ) utm=18 stm=5 core=6 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fcdbf9000-0x7fcdbfb000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=

  at java.lang.Object.wait! (Native method)
- waiting on <0x0c54fb7b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ (Thread.java:2127)
- locked <0x0c54fb7b> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park (Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos (LockSupport.java:201)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:670)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection (SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection (SQLiteSession.java:894)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:586)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query (SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:399)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query (SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.managers.storagemanager.StorageManager.query (StorageManager.java:1011)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.managers.storagemanager.StorageManager.a (StorageManager.java:1218)
- locked <0x00f0bd98> (a java.lang.Object)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.managers.storagemanager.StorageManager.a (StorageManager.java:1205)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.managers.storagemanager.StorageManager.F (StorageManager.java:1812)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.managers.e.a (LanguageManager.java:63)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.managers.e.a (LanguageManager.java:84)
  at com.norwegian.travelassistant.tabbar.TabsActivity.onCreate (TabsActivity.java:141)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6705)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1119)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2664)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2772)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1515)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6217)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Please tell if you need more info

Comment: Seems like its connected to database I/O in the main thread.
I have never had this problem before, but maybe something has changed...

Comment: My fix was to delete and re-intanceiate the database. An ugly fix, but it worked. Seemed like a lot of the users got corrupt databases with the release. Why, I have no idea...

Answer (score 91):

The crash is caused by the ANR on your Service, prior to the launch of your Activity.

If a user launches your app during a long-running task in your Service, the Activity will not be created until the task on the service finishes. This waiting might look bizarre to the user launching your app, and they then swipe your app away in the task switcher, which removes the task record from the ActivityManager (but process is still kept alive at this time).

When the long-running task on the service finally returns, it unblocks the activity from launching, but at this time the activity will throw `ActivityRecord not found` exception because it was removed already.

The following sequence diagram might explain the crash better.[image]

Credit goes to YogiAi, who originally investigated the issue in [this post](https://xiaozhuanlan.com/topic/0857213649).

Comment: I dont think this was the problem in my case. If you just waited for a long time, the app crashed. Even though you did not "kill" or "swipe" the application.

Reinitiate the DB worked, so somehow the DB got corrupt, and when I tried to access it, the app froze and crashed.

I dont know why...

Comment: the shared post need fees to read the full article, not helping much.

Comment: I can't open the link. is there any experience resolving this issue?

Comment: Can the problem appear if I call `finish()` in activity's `onCreate()`?

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev It should work fine to call finish() in onCreate()

Comment: So this problem existed and now it's not? Or what? There is no workaround? Seems it's at least till Android 9...

Answer (score 17):

There is a bug opened with Google, seems exclusive to Samsung on app upgrades

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62427912

Comment: Facing same issue on Samsung galaxy J8 running Android 9.

Comment: I got this only in Android 9

Comment: I got this on HUAWEI devices too. Was it really fixed? From which Android version?

Comment: I got it on Huawei nova 3i with Android 8.1.0. It is a rare crash and seems to happen when the device is in the background state. But a fix will be useful.

Comment: I can see this crash on a Redmi device + Android 9

Comment: The same problem in Huawei devices, not only in Samsung devices.

Answer (score 4):

One of reasons of this problem can be - memory leak.
In Houde's [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/qqqq245425070/article/details/79799104) he writes the app that uses EventBus to receive the event to close the Activity, and an Event was writing an internal class, that caused by a memory leak.

Memory leak causes activity not no launch but relaunch. That causes problem by his words.

Another [problem](https://blog.csdn.net/dreamfly130/article/details/80775105) could be Activity pause/stop/destroy timeout. It can lead to the same