# IllegalArgumentException: reportSizeConfigurations: ActivityRecord not found for: Token

Tags: android

I received the following bug report from a Moto E (4) Plus running Andorid 7.1.1:

**Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reportSizeConfigurations: ActivityRecord not found for: Token{9857068 ActivityRecord{774778b u0 com.my.app/.activities.SplashActivity t5607 f}}**

```
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1688)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1637)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.reportSizeConfigurations (ActivityManagerNative.java:7000)
android.app.ActivityThread.reportSizeConfigurations (ActivityThread.java:2820)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2759)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1495)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6196)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:888)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

that activity is the launch-activity and actually it does very little:

1. it reads the API token from shared prefs (if it exists)
2. it creates the OkHttpClient (with api token or without)
3. a 2 second delayed handler triggers the next activity

but judging from the stacktrace, the Android OS is still setting up the Activity.

Is this a bug in Android ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you get any solution for it.

Comment: no, nothing yet :(

Comment: Google takes about 3 years to fix anything once it's reported. Be sure to star the issue (see link) and add your own stacktrace and device/os info https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62427912

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309428/android-activitythread-reportsizeconfigurations-causes-app-to-freeze-with-black

Comment: Any Solution have been found ?

Comment: similar issue with Galaxy Note Fan Edition os v 9