# Xamarin app crashes on Samsung Galaxy S8 - no pattern identified

Tags: android, xamarin, samsung-galaxy

I am currently investigating startup crashes of Xamarin app. I haven't been able to identify any pattern, though it happens at startup and I have an impression it might be related to hot/cold start issue of some sort. The crash is intermittent and I did not find a way how to replicate it.

I have been able to capture the exception below and also find some potential explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309428/android-activitythread-reportsizeconfigurations-causes-app-to-freeze-with-black).

This information however did not help me to move forward. I have retrieved log files but did not find any relevant information; we use some logging feature on appcenter.ms but it appears the app crashes before it has chance to record any issues.

I have an impression (and this is how it was reported to me) that it happens on Samsung Galaxy S8, but cannot confirm with certainty.

I wonder if anyone has a similar experience and could point me to correct direction please?

Thank you

```
 at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reportSizeConfigurations: ActivityRecord not found for: Token{8e9afed ActivityRecord{d6d9e04 u0 nz.co.ami/md57aeffea354204b009d2a3b62eec46074.SplashScreen t-1 f}}
 at at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1963)
 at at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1905)
 at at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.reportSizeConfigurations(IActivityManager.java:9959)
 at at android.app.ActivityThread.reportSizeConfigurations(ActivityThread.java:3091)
 at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3034)
 at at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
 at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
 at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
 at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
 at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
 at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
 at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Seems like there is a bug already reported https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62427912

Also this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092952/3111083) is a good explanation of why this can happen

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @sunilsunny. I wonder if you are aware of any known workaround or solution to this until this is resolved? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any workarounds. It seems that bug is still not assigned to anyone. What you can do is after reproducing the issue, navigate to developer settings, ensure ‘USB debugging’ is enabled, then enable ‘Bug report shortcut’. To take bug report, hold the power button and select the ‘Take bug report’ option. Then upload that in the link I shared. So that they have more data to work on.